# How to correctly manipulate divs to create a tree with branches?

Tags: html, css

I have been asked to create a tree (like the plant) for a project to display results from a quiz. I need branches on both sides, 4 main branches, that have 5 other branches expending from them, as well as leaf's and potentially fruits but I cant seem to implement the fruits aspect. Im having issues placing my divs and understanding how to manipulate them for the wanted output.
This is what I have so far but I'd like to put two of the branches of the other side of the tree and also be able to extent more divs from those branch's as I've been asked to add more branch's to appear more as a tree.

[image]

```
<div class=tree-container>
  
  <figure class="result-tree">
    <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cognitive" class="cat-branch-r" style="width: 150px">
      <span class="leaf"></span>
      <span class="leaf"></span>
      <span class="leaf"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Physical" class="cat-branch-r" style="width: 200px">
      <span class="leaf"></span>
      <span class="leaf"></span>
      <span class="leaf"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Social Emotional" class="cat-branch-r" style="width: 180px">
      <span class="leaf"></span>
      <span class="leaf"></span>
      <span class="leaf"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Spiritual" class="cat-branch-r" style="width: 130px">
      <span class="leaf"></span>
      <span class="leaf"></span>
      <span class="leaf"></span>
      </figure>
    </div>
```

I was attempting to make css for ".result-tree .cat-branch-l" and change the 2nd and 4th branch classes to the class cat-branch-l but I could never get it to go to the left side of the div. I understand it cant be done in the way I was attempting however I dont know how I may be able to do this ... Below is an image of what I was attempting to create, any help or advise would be great!

I have removed the hover elements and the alteration of width as it is handled by a controller to give the different lengths to the branches. I just left in sample widths for branch length to avoid confusion.

```
    .tree-container {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .result-tree {
        width: 35px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: saddlebrown;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .result-tree .cat-branch-r {
        height: 25px;
        background-color: peru;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
    }

    .result-tree .cat-branch-l {
        height: 25px;
        background-color: peru;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        justify-content: left;
        transform: rotate(-130deg);
    }

    .result-tree .cat-branch-r .leaf {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: green;
        border-radius: 100% 0 100% 0;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }

    .result-tree .cat-branch-r:hover {
        height: 25px;
        background-color: rgb(214, 189, 164);
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
    }

    .result-tree .cat-branch-r .leaf:hover {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: rgb(42, 173, 42);
        border-radius: 100% 0 100% 0;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what a fruit is to be - is it a 'child' of a leaf or is it at the same level as a leaf?

Comment: I would say its the same level as the leaf's, your meant to hover over them and they give more information based on the quiz results, I guess id need to make an apple/orange shape and have it hang somehow. I was told to focus on the branches and leaf's if I couldn't do the fruits. @AHaworth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your "tree" is has `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column`. This means that all of the children in the tree are going to be rendered in a single column -- in your case, the branches on the right.

If we mentally split our tree vertically by drawing a line down the trunk, to have branches on both sides of the trunk we then have two columns. So what we need to do is change our structure to be, generally, this:

```html
<div class="tree">
  <div class="branches"> left branches </div>
  <div class="branches"> right branches </div>
</div>
```

The "tree", however, now needs to have its CSS updated. It can continue using flex layout, but it needs to have `flex-direction: row` so that the children are arranged horizontally. And then the new `branches` divs need to use flex layout and have `flex-direction: column`.

Once you've got that down, positioning the branches and leaves comes down to a game of fiddling with transforms and margins and stuff.

In the below snippet, created two 'branches' divs like I described above and moved your "left" branch into the set of branches that will render on the left side. I kind of guessed how you wanted the leaves oriented (I'm also bad at transforms so adjust as needed), and I didn't bother implementing the 'hover' logic because this was primarily about branch placement.

```css
.tree-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.result-tree {
  width: 35px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.branches {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.branch {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: peru;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.result-tree .cat-branch-r {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.result-tree .cat-branch-l {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: -30px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /*justify-content: left;*/
  transform: rotate(-130deg);
}

.result-tree .cat-branch-r .leaf {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100% 0 100% 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.result-tree .cat-branch-l .leaf {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100% 0 100% 0;
  transform: translateY(50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.result-tree .cat-branch-r:hover {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(214, 189, 164);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.result-tree .cat-branch-r .leaf:hover {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(42, 173, 42);
  border-radius: 100% 0 100% 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class=tree-container>

  <figure class="result-tree">
    <div class="branches branches-l">
      <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Grab Bag" class="branch cat-branch-l" style="width: 180px">
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="branches branches-r">
      <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cognitive" class="branch cat-branch-r" style="width: 150px">
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
      </div>
      <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Physical" class="branch cat-branch-r" style="width: 200px">
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
      </div>
      <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Social Emotional" class="branch cat-branch-r" style="width: 180px">
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
      </div>
      <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Spiritual" class="branch cat-branch-r" style="width: 130px">
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
        <span class="leaf"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
```

Now, you asked how to "correctly" do this, and honestly I wouldn't go this route at all. I'm truly impressed with what you came up with, but it's not accessible and it doesn't scale. I'm not entirely sure *how* I'd go about doing it without sitting down and thinking about use cases, but it wouldn't be like this.

Answer (score 1):

I got in a muddle trying to use flex because what you have is a nested structure (an actual tree structure) and basic HTML is good at those so here's an alternative approach.

Your question asks for the 'correct' approach and I would not say any one approach is correct or not - if it works. However, this might help.

What this snippet does is define all dimensions in terms of one given dimension - the height of the tree trunk. This can be altered as required but if it uses some unit relative to the viewport then it will be responsive without anything else having to be done. This snippet uses vmin.

The dimensions and the color of each element are defined in CSS variables.

Then it takes a simplistic approach to positioning. Twigs are nested inside branch elements which are inside the trunk element. You can add leaves/fruit to be nested inside twig elements.

Alternate child elements are then placed either side of their parent element so you get every other branch on the left of the trunk. This method can also be used for twigs and ultimately leaves/fruit to get things spaced out. And as an extra touch the last child twig and leaf in each element can be set to go at its end so things match up with your drawing better.

I haven't done all the CSS required for the final stage (rotating all the twigs if required, adding fruit/leaves to left and right of their twigs) so this is just to answer you main question initially - how to put the branches on either side of the trunk (and with them the twigs). If you decide not to have the intermediary twigs then replace them with fruit/leaves leaving out that extra nesting stage.

```html
<style>
.tree {
  --trunkH: 80vmin; /* all other dimensions are calculated in relation to this height */

  --treeH: calc( var(--trunkH) * 100 / 80); /* top 20% is for rotated branches */
  --treeW: var(--treeH);
  --treeC: lightblue;
   
  --trunkW: calc(var(--trunkH) / 12); 
  --trunkC: #8b4513;
  
  --branchW: calc(var(--treeW) / 2);
  --branchW: calc(var(--trunkW) * 5);
  --branchH: calc(var(--trunkH) / 16);
  --branchC: #cd853f;
  
  --twigW: calc(var(--branchH) / 10);
  --twigH: calc(var(--branchW) / 10);
  --twigH: calc(var(--branchH) * 1);
  --twigC: gray;
  
  --leafW: var(--twigH);
  --leafH: calc(var(--leafW) * 2);
  --leafC: green;
  
  --fruitW: var(--twigH);
  --fruitH: var(--fruitW);
  --appleC: red;
  --orangeC: orange;
}

.tree {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--treeW);
  height: var(--treeH);
  background-color: var(--treeC);
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.tree * {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.trunk {
  width: var(--trunkW);
  height: var(--trunkH);
  background-color: var(--trunkC);
  top: 20%;
  left: calc(50% - (var(--trunkW) / 2));
  border-radius: 2vmin 2vmin 0 0;
}

.branch {
  width: var(--branchW);
  height: var(--branchH);
  background-color: var(--branchC);
  top: calc(var(--n) * 2 * var(--branchH));
  border-radius: 2vmin;
  }
  
.branch:nth-child(odd) {
  left: calc(var(--trunkW) / 2);
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
.branch:nth-child(even) {
  right: calc(var(--trunkW) / 2);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.twig {
  width: var(--twigW);
  height: var(--twigH);
  background-color: var(--twigC);
}

.branch:nth-child(odd) .twig {
  right: calc(var(--n) * var(--branchW) / 16);
}

.branch:nth-child(odd) .twig:nth-child(odd) {
  top: calc(-1 * var(--twigH));
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.branch:nth-child(odd) .twig:nth-child(even) {
  top: var(--branchH);
}

.branch:nth-child(odd) .twig:last-child {
  left: 100%;
  top: calc(var(--branchH) / 2);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

/* twigs on the left hand branches */

.branch:nth-child(even) .twig {
  left: calc(var(--n) * var(--branchW) / 16);
}

.branch:nth-child(even) .twig:nth-child(odd) {
  top: calc(-1 * var(--twigH));
}

.branch:nth-child(even) .twig:nth-child(even) {
  top: var(--branchH);
}

.branch:nth-child(even) .twig:last-child {
  left: 0;
  top: calc(var(--branchH) / 2);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
}
/* 
.apple, .orange {
  width: var(--fruitW);
  height: var(--fruitW);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.apple {
  background-color: var(--appleC);
}

.orange {
  background-color: var(--orangeC);
}
*/

.tree *:nth-child(1) { --n: 1; }
.tree *:nth-child(2) { --n: 2; }
.tree *:nth-child(3) { --n: 3; }
.tree *:nth-child(4) { --n: 4; }
.tree *:nth-child(5) { --n: 5; }
.tree *:nth-child(6) { --n: 6; }
.tree *:nth-child(7) { --n: 7; }
.tree *:nth-child(8) { --n: 8; }

</style>
<body>
  <div class="tree">
    <div class="trunk">
      <div class="branch">
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="branch">
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
          <div class="apple"></div>
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="branch">
        <div class="twig">      
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="twig">      
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="branch">
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
          <div class="leaf"></div>
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="twig">
          <div class="leaf"></div>
          <div class="leaf"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's the simple initial snippet - it